# How to Integrate Pysimple Gui With Micropython

Tags: python, pysimplegui, micropython

I was wondering, if it is possible to integrate pysimplegui with micropython. Here is my example, I am creating a robotic arm, it is controlled with micropython, for simplicity I wanted to create a GUI to control the arm, is it possible to integrate them, like a button that controls a micropython code snippet?

Thanks In Advance For The Help

Answer (score 1):

> tkinter requires an underlying windowing system (e.g. Windows, X windows)
>
> PySimpleGUI need tkinter installed.

There's no tkinter for MicroPython, so PySimpleGUI won't work in MicroPython.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use PySimpleGUI with MicroPython, but there are a [range of GUI libraries](https://awesome-micropython.com/#gui) that you could use, depending on the MicroPython implementation and the screen that you are using for the display. You would need to provide more information about these aspects of your solution, and provide a specific coding problem or challenge that you are facing.